# MongoDB $slice preformance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, query-optimization

I have following Mongoose query & projection. Subdoc1.entries is array of subdocuments.

```
Model.findById(id, {
  value1: 1,
  'subdoc1.entries': { $slice: 70 },
  'subdoc2.value1': 1,
  'subdoc2.value2': 1,
})
```

As the `subdoc1.entries` gets larger, the query gets slower. With tens of thousands entries, the query might take up to ten seconds on DBaaS like mLab or MongoDB Atlas.

There seems to be mixed information about putting large arrays to subdocuments... Is it possible to optimize the query without redesigning database structure?